# Python - trying to deal with the bits of a file

Tags: python, encryption, bit

I have very recently started to learn Python, and I chose to learn things by trying to solve a problem that I find interesting. This problem is to take a file (binary or not) and encrypt it using a simple method, something like replacing every "1001 0001" in it with a "0010 0101", and vice-versa.

However, I didn't find a way to do it. When reading the file, I can create an array in which each element contains one byte of data, with the read() method. But how can I replace this byte with another one, if it is one of the bytes I chose to replace, and then write the resulting information into the output encrypted file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you already taken a look at the [**Bitwise Operators**](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)?

Comment: So far I have been playing with reading the file, and displaying it on the screen, or writing it to a new file. Not much, but a start...

Comment: I will take a look at the Bitwise operators, thanks Rik!

Answer (score 2):

To swap bytes `10010001` and `00100101`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string

a, b = map(chr, [0b10010001, 0b00100101])
translation_table = string.maketrans(a+b, b+a) # swap a,b

with open('input', 'rb') as fin, open('output', 'wb') as fout:
     fout.write(fin.read().translate(translation_table))
```

Answer (score 1):

read() returns an immutable string, so you'll first need to convert that to a list of characters.  Then go through your list and change the bytes as needed, and finally join the list back into a new string to write to the output file.

```
filedata = f.read()
filebytes = list(filedata)
for i, c in enumerate(filebytes):
    if ord(c) == 0x91:
        filebytes[i] = chr(0x25)
newfiledata = ''.join(filebytes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I used something similar to this to replace each bit in the file by 00ff minus the value of this bit. Here is the resulting code (".cfh" is the extension I created to my program):


import sys
import os

input = file(sys.argv[1], "rb")
content = input.read()
bytes = list(content) 

for i in range(0, len(bytes)):
 bytes[i] = chr(0xff - ord(bytes[i]))

newfiledata = ''.join(bytes)

if(sys.argv[1].find(".cfh") != -1):
 output = file(sys.argv[1].replace(".cfh", ""), "w")
else:
 output = file(sys.argv[1]+".cfh", "w")

output.write(newfiledata)
os.remove(sys.argv[1])

Comment: (had trouble with formatting here...)

Thanks for the help! I used something similar to this to replace each bit in the file by 00ff minus the value of this bit. Here is the resulting code (".cfh" is the extension I created to my program): 

http://pastebin.com/i8h3Ar9D

Answer (score 0):

Following Aaron's answer, once you have a string, then you can also use `translate` or `replace`:

```
In [43]: s = 'abc'

In [44]: s.replace('ab', 'ba')
Out[44]: 'bac'

In [45]: tbl = string.maketrans('a', 'd')

In [46]: s.translate(tbl)
Out[46]: 'dbc'
```

Docs: [Python `string`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry about this somewhat relevant wall of text -- I'm just in a teaching mood.

If you want to optimize such an operation, I suggest using [numpy](https://numpy.org/). The advantage is that the entire translation operation is done with a single numpy operation, and those are written in C, so it is about as fast as you can get it using python.

In the below example I simply [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor) every byte with `0b11111111` using a lookup table -- first element is the translation of `0b0000000`, the second the translation of `0b00000001`, third `0b00000010`, and so on. By altering the lookup table, you can do any kind of translation that does not change within the file.

```
import numpy as np
import sys

data = np.fromfile(sys.argv[1], dtype="uint8")
lookup_table = np.array(
    [i ^ 0xFF for i in range(256)], dtype="uint8")
lookup_table[data].tofile(sys.argv[2])
```

To highlight the simplicity of it all I've done no argument checking. Invoke script like this:

```
python name_of_script.py input_file.txt output_file.txt
```

To directly answer your question, if you want to swap `0b10010001` and `0b00100101`, you replace the `lookup_table = ...` line with this:

```
lookup_table = np.array(range(256), dtype="uint8")
lookup_table[0b10010001] = 0b00100101
lookup_table[0b00100101] = 0b10010001
```

Of course there is no lookup table encryption that isn't easily broken using [frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis). But as you may know, encryption using a [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) is unbreakable, as long as the pad is safe. This modified script encrypts or decrypts using a one-time pad (which you'll have to create yourself, store to a file, and somehow (there's the rub) securely transmit to the intended recipient of the message):

```
data = np.fromfile(sys.argv[1], dtype="uint8")
pad = np.fromfile(sys.argv[2], dtype="uint8")
(data ^ pad[:len(data)]).tofile(sys.argv[3])
```

Example usage (linux):

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=pad.bin bs=512 count=5
$ python pytrans.py pytrans.py pad.bin encrypted.bin
```

Recipient then does:

```
$ python pytrans.py encrypted.bin pad.bin decrypted.py
```

Viola! Fast and unbreakable encryption with three lines (plus two import lines) in python.